# jquery load simple data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jquery to load html content stored in 'result.html' page.The paths in the program are correct.But,when I click the button,the content is not loaded.Here is the "main.html" file:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>the title</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#driver").click(function(event){
      $('#stage').load("jquery/result.html");
   });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Click on the button to load result.html file:</p>
<div id="stage">STAGE</div>
<input type="button" id="driver" value="Load Data" />
</body>
</html>
```

This is the 'result.html' file:

```
 <html>
    <body>
    <h1>Result</h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: Content coming from same domain? Please post any console errors. Press F12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your console you should be getting the following error

[image]

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

you are trying to perform `XMLHttpRequest(AJAX)` to another domain.

This is restricted due to security reasons.

for more details see:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Answer (score 0):

Your code basically works for me. There **must be a problem with your url**. If i copy your code and try it locally with another file it works fine.

If you're running your code from a static file, try to switch it to any webserver. It can make a big diffrence since some browser don't allow ajax requests to local urls if you're using them from static files.

Comment: I think URL is not a problem because he have used absolute url

Comment: Did you use a webserver?